# how to save BERT word embedding as .vec similar to word2vec

Tags: vector, word2vec, word-embedding, glove, torchtext

I want to use the generated BERT word embedding as a vector for building the vocab in Torchtext 
I can load vectors such as GloVe or word2vec
but I didn't know how to save the word embedding from BERT to a format acceptable by Torchtext vocab

when I try this code

```
txt_field.build_vocab(train, vectors=bertVec)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Got input vectors of type <class 'torch.Tensor'>, expected str or Vectors object
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward way to create a Vocab for BERT embeddings.

Below is the reason:

1. If you look at Mikolv's or GLOVE's embeddings, there are just words embeddings computed on a huge corpus of the data. For Mikolov's embedding, you have about 3M words and their embeddings.
   However, BERT uses word-piece embeddings, and there are roughly 30K words-piece in its vocab.
2. Now you may think of computing word-piece embedding. Yes, technically you must be able to do it. However, for BERT you cannot. This is because, in case of Mikolov or Glove, embedding vectors are just based on the words and depends on the context which influences while calculating the embedding values. But, in case of BERT, and embedding is based on 3 factors:

   1. WORD(-piece) embedding,
   2. Position embedding and
   3. Segment embedding.

So, the same word "Hello", may have different embedding based on which position of the sentence it would appear, this is by the influence of Position embedding.

Therefore, it would likely be impossible to construct a vocabulary for words using BERT, as same words may take different embeddings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I did not understand what you mean by the Segment embedding

Comment: Bert is trained on two tasks, namely, Masked language model and next sentence prediction task. To train on next sentence prediction task, it maintains segment embedding. Two tokes from the same sentence (segment) will have same segment embeddings (ideally all the tokens from the same segment will have same segment embeddings)

Comment: The details on the embeddings are infact explained in the paper.